# File not found even though it is there. .doc and .txt work but .jpg and .png don't

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I have this code:

```
public void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs file)
{
    Console.WriteLine("created called");

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{textBox2.Text}", file.Name);

    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        if (trueFalse == "true")
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine($"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\OneDrive", file.Name)))
            {
                File.Copy(files[0], Path.Combine($"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\OneDrive", file.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
            }
        }

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(textBox3.Text, file.Name)))
        {
            File.Move(files[0], Path.Combine(textBox3.Text, file.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File {file.Name} not found in directory {textBox2.Text}.");
    }
}
```

When I test it on `.txt` and `.doc` and `.docx` files, it works and moves and copies, but `.png` and `.jpg` don't, and go to the else{} block.

I have no idea what causes this behavior. Any help?

Comment: What is the value of trueFalse?

Comment: BTW: instead of `$"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}"`, better use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`

Comment: "and go to the else{} block" - which of the three `else` blocks in your code? And what is `textBox2.Text` and `textBox3.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the
Directory.GetFiles()
method returns an array of filenames that match the search pattern,it's possible
Directory.GetFiles()
is not matching the image files correctly. You could try changing the search pattern to include all image formats, for example:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles($"{textBox2.Text}", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => f.EndsWith(".png") || f.EndsWith(".jpg") || etc..).ToArray();
```

This will get all the files in the directory and filter the results to files with the specified extensions.

Alternatively, you could also check if the file exists before preforming any actions on it:

```
    string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine($"{textBox2.Text}", file.Name);
    string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(textBox3.Text, file.Name);
    if (File.Exists(sourceFilePath))
    {
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            if (trueFalse == "true")
            {
                if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(pathstring), file.Name)))
                {
                    File.Copy(sourceFilePath, Path.Combine(pathstring), file.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
            }
        }

        if (!File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
        {
            File.Move(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File {file.Name} not found in directory {textBox2.Text}.");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"File {file.Name} not found in directory {textBox2.Text}.");
}
```

This will first check if the file exists in the source directory before attempting to move or copy it, and will print an error message if the file is not found.